# Set expiration date and time with before_create Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am adding expire function to advertisement. Expire should contain data and time Like this: **12.06.12  14:24**

At this point I done like this:
I have additional column in database for advertisements called **expiration**

```
before_create :set_expiration_date

   def set_expiration_date
        self.expiration =  Date.today + 56.days
    end
```

This works great. Now in view I want to see this expiration date.

**Advertisement#show**

```
<%= @advertisement.expiration.to_formatted_s(:db) %>
```

but it gives me just this `2015-02-06`

When I changed **set_expiration_date** to:

```
 def set_expiration_date
      self.expiration =  Time.now + 56.days
 end
```

That still was like `2015-02-06` without time.

So I wonder if only soulution would be having two columns **expiration_date** and **expiration_time** to my advertisement table.

Then having like this in my model:

```
 before_create :set_expiration_date
 before_create :set_expiration_time


 def set_expiration_date
      self.expiration_date =  Date.today + 56.days
 end

 def set_expiration_time
      self.expiration_time =  Time.now
 end
```

I think this solution is very ugly.

Is there any other simpier solution to my problem ? How can I store in single column date and time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the format of your `expiration_time` column? Is it `datetime`? Please show your migration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `expiration` from `date` to `datetime`, and why do you don't use `strftime` to beter format your output

example:

```
<%= @advertisement.expiration.strftime("%b %d %Y, %H:%M") %>
```

See also [strftime format meaning](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime#651-Format-meaning)

Answer (score 3):

[Change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19678070/19093) the datatype of `expiration` from `date` to `datetime`.