# ruby on rails - add end_time upon record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to have a record with ends_at column which is suppose to have the created_at value with 5 minutes added to it for instance:

```
Class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_end_time

  private
    def set_end_time
      self.ends_at = self.created_at + 5.minutes
    end
end
```

this saves the ends_at column as a null in the database

Comment: Answer is found https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443303/6361142 [duplicate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fire `after_create` hook. It gets triggered after **Rails** calls SQL `INSERT` command. So you setup `ends_at` already when object was saved to the database and it will not be saved again. Object with initialized `ends_at` not going anywhere and then just get cleared from the memory.

Replace your hook with `before_create` and it should do the trick for you.

Comment: `before_create ` also doesn't work, reading up on related questions such as adding an expiration date https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443303/6361142, might be caused due the dataype of `ends_at`

Comment: Can you please: 1. paste db/schema piece for this table? 2. Check that `set_end_time` gets really called in `before_create` case with `logger` or `debugger`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save the record

```
def set_end_time
  self.ends_at = self.created_at + 5.minutes
  save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One hard way to do it would be to set a default value when a row is created if the migration
for exemple
change_column_default :posts, :end_time, "current_timestamp + (5 ||' minutes')::interval" if you use postgres for exemple.

But only do that if you are sure that this is not going to change soon.
If it is, then setting a before_create hook with a custom setter is the way to go (Just be sure that your field is of datetime type)