# Getting PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a class Customer

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:unconfirmed]

  default_scope { order updated_at: :desc }

  scope :unconfirmed, -> { where(status: 0) }
end
```

Status field in Schema is defined as integer with a default 0.

In development, SQLite, all is working fine but in a production, PostgresSQL, when I try to run **Customer.unconfirmed** I am getting an error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: ...s".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."status" = 0  ORDER...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."status" = 0  ORDER BY "customers"."updated_at" DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: ...s".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."status" = 0  ORDER...
```

Can someone help me with finding out what is going on here?

Comment: just `status: 0::Boolean` instead of `status: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with `enum` feature, you **MUST** need to make the [*enum* field as **integer**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). But as per the Exception you got, it is clear that you made the field `status` as *boolean*.

You can inspect the column type in your production server. Open your rails console as `rails c production`. Then `Customer.columns_hash['status'].type` to see the type of the column.

Add a new migration to [change the column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191405/change-a-column-type-from-date-to-datetime-during-ror-migration) from *boolean* to *integer*, and then apply the migration.
Then you can do as :

```
scope :unconfirmed, -> { where(status: :unconfirmed) }
#or
scope :unconfirmed, -> { where(status: 0) }
```

Comment: but status is set up as integer I have add_column :customers, :status, :integer, default: 0 in my migration file

Comment: @Kocur4d See if there is an pending migration in your *Production* environment.

Comment: @Kocur4d Do in your production after opening the console as `rails c production` -->  `Customer.columns_hash['status'].type` to inspect its datatype..

Comment: It shows type as :boolean, I have no idea how this happen. My migration files are up to date and it is integer in there. What will be the best way to change it to integer via psql?

Comment: @Kocur4d Well write another migration to change the [type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191405/change-a-column-type-from-date-to-datetime-during-ror-migration). Don't edit any existing migration file.

Comment: yes that was it, I have modified existing migration and this was the problem. Changing types for pg is not as straight forward as for sqllite it is not going to let you do simply chage :table, :column, :type. Thank you especially for Customer.columns_hash['status'].type